# Multi-Page WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am new to desktop application development and have a pretty basic question. I have a WPF form named MainWindow, how should I go about having multiple pages on this, such as "User Management", "Manage Content" etc..

I think I have the following options:

1. Use multiple forms
2. Tabs
3. Group Box?

Any clarification would be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I went with that suited what I was looking for was using [WPF Pages](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation) but thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 10):

- Well in my most recent application I started by using a TabControl, that's a safe and rather easy way to go.
- Recently switched the tabcontrol with a StackPanel with a series of Expanders inside. I styled the expanders to have them display the header vertically and expand horizontally... somewhat similar to the first [xbox dashboard](http://www.winsupersite.com/content/content/127500/reviews/xbox360_xbl_01.jpg). And it looks and works great! =)
- Another alternative would be to use a Page instead of a window... Then you would just have to Navigate to each different page.

EDIT:
[Here's](http://azerdark.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/multi-page-application-in-wpf/) an example of a multi-page application... might be close to what you need.

Answer (score 5):

There are **many ways** to do that, such as creating UserControl and show them in the run time.But using TabControl is fast and safe.

Just Use TabControl and place your pages in tab items .Then hide the header of TabControl by setting the value **Visibility="Collapsed"** to each TabItem.

The result is as below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**As you see the headers are hide and you can switch to each page you want.**

Comment: Wouldn't this be super slow on an app with hundreds of pages? The load time would be too much. You would almost have to load each tab on demand as the user navigates around. E.g. if you want to navigate to Tab3, check if (Tab3.Content == null) { LoadTab3(); }

Answer (score 2):

Create 
usercontrol(wpf): UserManagement
usercontrol2(wpf) : ManageContent

place control "ContentControl" in the main window

Run the code on click of button:
//Displays usercontrol1
contentControl.content = new UserManagement();

//Displays usercontrol2
contentControl.content = new ManageContent();

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to give you an example of something I have in one of my applications.

The app has two windows: the main window and another one (also derived from Window and equipped with the appropriate buttons and event handlers) that is used as a start dialog. The start dialog is called in the constructor of the main window like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    startdlg m_dlg;
    // ...

    public MainWindow() 
    {
        m_dlg = new startdlg();

        if ((bool)m_dlg.ShowDialog())
        {
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            Close();
        }
        // ...
```