# How to create Multi-Window/page Application in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new in WPF & i have to create  multi-page application in WPF, in other words an application which just consists of one window but it has multiple pages.

How to Create this application from starting kindly help.

Comment: You can use two different `UserControls` at one page. OR look at [Multi Page App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108669/multi-page-wpf-application)

Comment: To quote several million people : "There are many ways that lead to rome."

Comment: Use Tabcontrol.Then hide the header of tabs by Visibility="Collapsed".